# Why is retrieving a ResultSet from Oracle stored procedure so slow?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have to improve some code where an Oracle stored procedure is called from a Java program. Currently the code is really really slow: up to about 8 seconds on my development machine. On the same machine, if I directly call an SQL query that does about the same treatment and returns the same data, it takes under 100 ms...

The code creates a CallableStatement, registers one of the output parameters to be an Oracle cursor, and then retrieves the cursor using the getObject method of the statement and parse it to ResultSet:

```
cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call PKG_ESPECEW.P_ListEspece( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) }");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
[...]
cstmt.executeQuery();
rs = (ResultSet)cstmt.getObject(4);
rs.setFetchSize(1000); //supposed to help ?

options = new HashMap<String, String>(1000);
rs.next() //added that to measure exactly the length of the first call

while(rs.next()) {
    [...]
}
```

I put some timestamps in the code to know which part is taking so long. The result: The first call to `rs.next()` is taking up to various seconds. The result sets are average, from 10 to a couple thousands rows. As I said before, handling similar result sets coming from a regular PreparedStatement takes 10-100 ms depending the size.

Is anything wrong with the code? How do I improve it? I'll do direct SQL where critical if I haven't any other solution, but I'd prefer a solution that allows me to not rewrite all the procedures!

Here is the definition of the stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE P_ListEspece(P_CLT_ID IN ESPECE.ESP_CLT_ID%TYPE,     -- Langue de l'utilisateur
                        P_ESP_GROUP_CODE IN ESPECE.ESP_CODE%TYPE,-- Code du groupe ou NULL
                        P_Filter IN VARCHAR2,                   -- Filtre de la requête
                        P_Cursor OUT L_CURSOR_TYPE,             -- Curseur
                        P_RecordCount OUT NUMBER,               -- Nombre d'enregistrement retourne
                        P_ReturnStatus OUT NUMBER);              -- Code d'erreur
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `OracleCallableStatement.getCursor` instead of `getObject`?

Comment: I would have to cast the CallableStatement to OracleCallableStatement, but I am using DBCP and the CallableStatement is actually a "proxy" provided by DBCP, so I would get an Exception (I tried it).

Comment: For the fetching, to optimize it over the network, you should use setRowPrefetch. This has a tremendous impact. While with setFetchSize it is around 20-30% , Prefetch can be up to 10 times on huge datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I thought the procedure was executed, then it's result stored in oracle server's memory, and finally transmitted back to the client (the java app) through the cursor and result set and JDBC"

That's incorrect. 
What oracle returns as a cursor is basically a pointer to a query (all ready with any bind variables). It has not materialized the result set in memory. It could be a massive result set of millions/billions of rows.

So it could well be a slow query that takes a long time to deliver results.

Comment: I talked with the DB guy that takes care of the DB and it seems the query execute inside the SP was actually the problem, becaus it was calling a function that was opening another cursor for each record found. He removed this call and the execution time went down to less than 1 second. It is still quite slow but already more acceptable. I guess the query itself can still be improved and the problem is actually with the query and not the transmission of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the stored procedure is doing some data conversion/massaging forth and back (e.g. `int` <--> `varchar`). This is known to take a lot of time in case of large tables. Ensure that you've declared the right datatypes in the SP arguments and are setting the right datatypes in `CallableStatement`.

Comment: Actually it's not reading or setting the SP arguments that takes time, it is reading from the ResultSet that is itself an argument of the SP. I'll update the question with th SP definition. So you think that type conversion could be an issue in this case ?

Comment: You told that it's faster with `PreparedStatement`, so the problem is likely with the SP. If any column value needs to be (implicitly) converted, then it will take time, especially when used in SP's `WHERE` clause.

Comment: But it is not the cstmt.executeQuery(); that is slow, it's the result set browsing.  I thought the procedure was executed, then it's result stored in oracle server's memory, and finally transmitted back to the client (the java app) through the cursor and result set and JDBC. But maybe I am wrong ? I am an Oracle/PLSQL ignorant. Would the procedure be executed "step by step" when the result set is read ?

Comment: I chaked all the mapping of the parameters : they were all correct except the second one. It is of type NUMBER but I was applying the setInt method on the statement. I corrected this, but unfortunately it didn't fix the slow response time... I think that the conversion of this parameter would be done only once by Oracle, so not much influence...

Answer (score 1):

How long does it take to execute the procedure outside of Java? Check with a script like this in SQL*Plus:

```
var ref refcursor
var cnt number
var status number
exec p_listespece (xx, yy, zz, :ref, :cnt, :status);--replace with actual values
print :ref
```

If it takes more than 10-100 ms, your problem may come from the stored procedure.

Comment: Actually I don't have SQLPlus or the oracle client installed on my dev machine. I do most thnigs with SQLDevelopper, and ask the DBA for the rest. I'll check with him tomorrow. Or you know if I can execute plsql directly from SQLDev ?

Comment: I installed the oracle client and sql plus and tried this. The display of the result in the command line took forever, but it was probably slowed down by the command line printing in windows command line. Anyway, the problem is with the SP itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, we solved (me and the oracle dedicated guy) by changing the returned parameter from a cursor to a varchar, that was the plain query the stored was executing internally.
this was an huge implementation, I don't know if this is applicable for your scenario.

here's the snippet :

`

```
String sql = "call MyStored(?,?,?,?)";
CallableStatement st = Conn.prepareCall(sql);
st.setInt(1, 10);
st.setInt(2, 20);
st.setInt(3, 30);
st.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);

st.execute();

String query = (String) st.getObject(4);
Statement stmt = Conn.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
[...]
//work with resultset
[...]
stmt.close();
stmt = null;
```

`